# How to disable "long descriptions" of commands in ZSH

Tags: shell, zsh, autocomplete

I have a program named `fhome` that provides shell completion for Zsh:

```
$ fhome <tab>
config     -- Manage system configuration
event      -- Manage events
help    h  -- Shows a list of commands or help for one command
object  o  -- Manage objects
```

I'd like to disable the short options (`-h`, `-o`) and descriptions, so the result after pressing `<tab>` would look like this:

```
$ fhome <tab>
config event help object
```

Is this possible, and if yes – how? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of aspects of completion can be [configured through `zstyle`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Overview-2). If the completion code for `fhome` follows the usual principles:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:fhome:*:*' verbose no
```

There may be ways to generate this presentation of completions that aren't affected by the `verbose` style. If this code doesn't work, I can't offer more help without seeing the completion code. The transcript from `^X?` ([`_complete_debug`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fcomplete_005fdebug-_0028_005eX_003f_0029)) might also help.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. The completion code was copy-pasted from the urfave/cli Go package. Here is its code, in case anyone wonders: https://github.com/bartekpacia/fhome/blob/33e7ead5bcd09b4068ef988036d143d6727db207/autocomplete/zsh_autocomplete_fhome